# Hypothesis test for testing statistical difference of two samples of 4 instances each

Tags: hypothesis-testing, small-sample

I have been asked to perform a statistical analysis of two very small samples (just 4 instances per group) and I want to assess whether they come from the same or different distributions.

So we have a set of 10 continuous variables and two groups of 4 samples.

This example comes form psychology, in which obtaining the data is immensely expensive. I am used to work with thousands of instances, so I am not sure about which test to use. To me this would be insufficient data to perform any valid analysis, but still this is not a valid answer.

Is there any test that allows to compare the underlying distributions with such small sample size?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: What aspects of the distributions do you wish to compare?

Comment: @whuber As a first approach, the means.

Comment: That's exactly what a t-test does.

Comment: @whuber So even if I only have 4 samples and unequal variance, Is the t-test the best option to compare means?

Comment: There is a version of the t-test designed for unequal variances (Welch).  With four observations per group you can still detect large differences.  Of course this application builds on statistical assumptions.  If you can't make any at all, you can still inquire about the chance that a random division of eight observations would result in two radically different subsets. Just beware of *post hoc* hypothesizing: to get any kind of legitimate significance out of such a small dataset, you have to be absolutely rigorous in framing your questions and analyzing the results.